# Anaconda: %run from folder in python path

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, pythonpath

I have a folder in my python path, called `test_folder`, inside of which is a file called `test_file.py`. The folder was added permanently to the python path by entering it as a line in a file I made, `.../Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/my_folders.pth`.

If I type (in a jupyter notebook) `import test_file`, it is imported, as expected. However, if instead I type `%run test_file`, then `test_file.py` is not found. I would like to be able to `%run` files that are in folders in my python path, just as I can import them.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just import the functions you need and run those? This looks to me like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/251060)

Comment: Admittedly there's some truth to that, but I guess there are three reasons. 1. I'm adapting code from notebooks where it seems like other people have found a way to do this, it would be nice not to have to go through and change those lines. 2. This is the first time I've started playing with magic functions in python, I'm learning about their uses and limitations as I go. 3. I sometimes like to play around with different syntax or ways of doing things, e.g., for loops vs. list comprehension. This is an example of that.